# Disable onClick effect toolbar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a `Toolbar` where I put my logo, in the app when I click the logo this shows a clicking effect and I want no effect at all.

if I put this on my code does not work:

```
    toolbar.setClickable(false);
    toolbar.setEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Neither on my xml

```
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

This is how I put the logo:

```
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(deviceStateListener,intentFilter);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_lycos_logo_home);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your `Toolbar` XML to have an `ImageView`, like this:

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="ANY_HEX_COLOR"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_lycos_logo_home"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then, on your `ActionBarActivity`, set this `Toolbar` as your supportActionBar.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And if you want to remove the title and just leave your logo there, try:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

First set the toolbar as `ActionBar` and then set the NavaigationIcon

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_lycos_logo_home);
```